# Алгоритм решения задач программирования

Tags: алгоритм

Часто бывает при постановке задачи с программирования возникают проблемы именно с алгоритмическим решением. Приведу пример задач, найти количество различных элементов массива и т.д. Не могу придумать алгоритм или же придумываю и возникают проблемы с уточнением деталей работы алгоритма и их реализации. Часто довольно когда сам не могу додуматься, проблемы с алгоритмическим мышлением видно и опыта мало очень. Для решения проблемы обычно спрашиваю у знающего человека, гугл или на форуме. Могу смотреть аналогичный код похожей задачи или читать вариант решения описанный словами. Возникли вопросы.

1. Насколько это полезно или вредно?
2. Как вы мне посоветуете бороться с этим?

Comment: Это полезно. Надо только потом, по памяти, попытаться самому запрограммировать прочитанное.

Answer (score 2):

Тренируйтесь в решении чисто алгоритмических задач: обработка массивов, списков, деревьев, графов. Могу порекомендовать пару отличных книг на эту тему:

- Дональд Э. Кнут -  Искусство программирования
- Стивен Скиена - Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке
- Томас Кормен, Чарльз Лейзерсон, Рональд Ривест, Клиффорд Штайн - Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ

Поиск решения своими силами даст вам гораздо больше опыта, чем переписывание чужих решений с форума. Поэтому решать, решать, решать. В этом плане еще полезно участвовать в олимпиадах типа TopCoder.

Comment: К книгам могу добавить Ч. Уэзерелл - "Этюды для программистов". Только не знаю, реально ли ее сейчас найти (1982 год).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего пытаться решить своими силами, иногда на это может уйти уйма времени, но зато будет идти развитие мышления.

Вредно ли прибегать к чужой помощи? Ну, смотря какая помощь, если тебе сразу всё решили, от этого толку нет. Лучше спрашивать какие-то детали, благодаря которым ты сможешь остальное додумать сам.